# How to add string parameters in lookup method in jdbc connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource

In my web application I'm using JDBC connectivity basically its working fine with below code

```
connObj = DriverManager.getConnection(dbaseUrl, usrName, Paswrd);
```

But when I'm using veracode tool its showing flaw as J2EE Bad Practice:getConnection so that i need to implement.

```
InitialContext ctx= new InitialContext();
DataSource dsrc=(DataSource)ctx.lookup(dbaseUrl, usrName, Paswrd);
dsrc.getConnection();
```

How can I pass 3 parameters in lookup so that it should not disturb my previous flow of code. Can anybody guide me please?

Comment: You can't. You first need to define a data source and then use that here. Is this a web application or a standalone application ? For standalone applications you would need to create an InitialContext and then bind it in your code. For web applications its a good practice to define data sources in the server.xml file using <Resource> tags.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the lookup method parameter. But you can use [bind or rebind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) methods of InitialContext to retrieve your datasource.See sample

```
 ctx.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/nameofmyjdbcresource", dsrc);
```

For details example check [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit).

Answer (score 0):

A `DataSource` is a connection to one database and you configure a DataSource with a single username and password. If you really need specific (and changing) usernames/passwords depending on application logic, then you can use [`DataSource.getConnection(String username, String password)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). However keep in mind with some (most?) connection pools this will give you a non-pooled connection.

If you want to access a different database (or a different configuration), then you need to specify a data source for each database you want to access and ask for that specific data source.

If that is not possible for your situation, then you should just ignore/suppress the veracode warning and continue using `DriverManager`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream pfile = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
            prop.load(pfile);
            pfile.close();
            Properties info = new Properties();
            info.put("user",prop.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
            info.put("password",prop.getProperty("jdbc.pwd"));

            Driver d = (Driver) 
Class.forName(prop.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")).newInstance();
            con = 
DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("jdbc.url"),info);
```